# Can arc diff exclude certain files in Phabricator?

Tags: git, phabricator

Some C++ files are system generated and not necessary to review. In addition, these files are rather large and sometimes it causes "the request to exceeds the capacity limit". A better place to review it is to compare the new schema and old schema files. These files are part of the commit so I don't want to use .gitignore against them.

This is one other post about this I found on internet but it wasn't helpful. http://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-arc-diff-to-exclude-some-files-in-Phabricator

Answer (score 13):

I did some searches and I found out answers myself.

It's possible that you've accidentally included something not suitable for human review, e.g. binary files or generated files.

Solution includes:

1. If you put the string `@generated` anywhere in a file then Differential will not try to review it. (this may not stop arcanist from trying to upload it however)
2. If you supply the `--less-context` flag to arcanist then instead of sending whole files it will only send a small amount of surrounding context.
3. Use `.gitattributes`. Here's an example of using `.gitattributes` to exclude messages files from diffs, see the the Git Book for more information. Note that you may need to commit the new `.gitattributes` before it has an affect on your diffs.

   ```
   *_hugetext.h         -diff
   *_hugetext.cpp       -diff
   ```
4. `arc diff --skip-binaries`
   If you mark a file as binary and supply the `--skip-binaries` flag then arcanist will not try to upload it. Please see the Git Book for an example of marking a file as binary.
5. `git diff origin/master... --stat`
   If you're using Git, you can get more insight into why your diff is large by using this command to examine the `diff stat`. (assuming your base is `origin/master`)
6. `git diff origin/master... | wc --bytes`
   If you're using Git, you can easily see the size of the diff arcanist is trying to upload with this command. (assuming your base is `origin/master`)

Comment: my file name is abc/exy/xyz.js how can i ignore this file if. i don`t want to modify file content because it was auto generated file and have a very larg size.